# Minimize and maximize button in wsl

Tags: gnome, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dconf, gsettings

I am currently using `wsl2` with Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11. I am not able to see minimize/maximize button on the titlebar. I first discovered this problem with sublime text, but when I tried other apps, they had the same problem. To solvw this I tried the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"
```

This was the output:

```
(process:26220): dconf-WARNING **: 18:15:12.690: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

My `DISPLAY` environment variable is also set to `:0`. I also, tried to fix this through the `dconf-editor`, but that produced the same error.

Please tell me how to fix this.
Thanks.